# Builds fail after changing branches away from .NET Core 2.0

Tags: .net, git, visual-studio

We are working to port one of our libraries over to .NET Core 2.0.
After doing some work on the migration branch, I change branches to work on something else. Now all my builds fail with this error:

[image: Build error]

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Your project.json doesn't have a runtimes section. You should add '"runtimes": { "win": { } }' to your project.json and then re-run NuGet restore.  Synovia.Service.Common  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\15.0\Microsoft.NuGet.targets 186
```

To resolve the issue, temporarily, I delete the entire contents of the repo then do:

```
git fetch --force
git reset --hard origin/develop
```

Assuming the branch I need to work on is develop in this scenario.

There is not a project.json anywhere that I can find the repo.

The workaround is ok for now, but, will be a real pain if it persists once we merge this migration into dev.

Keep in mind this all builds fine on the migration branch and doesnt throw this error until I change branches.

Comment: Please include errors as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the contents of the `obj` folder resolved this for me. Had to manually delete the contents as a clean or rebuild wasnt working.

Comment: you can use `git clean' for this